# Additional include directory set to an empty environment variable breaks Visual C++ build

Tags: c, visual-c++, environment-variables, include-path

I have a project in Visual C++ 2008 where an include directory's name comes from an environment variable:

```
AdditionalIncludeDirectories="&quot;..\include&quot;;&quot;$(EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR)&quot;"
```

(Project properties → Configuration Properties → C/C++ → General → Additional Include Directories in the GUI)

When the `EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR` environment variable is not defined, the project does not compile and I get weird errors:.

```
1>Compiling...
1>WIN32
1>c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'WIN32': No such file or directory
1>foo.c
```

and more errors that indicate that the `WIN32` symbol is not defined. `WIN32` is defined in the `PreprocessorDefinitions` (`PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;MORE_STUFF"`)

When I look at the `BuildLog.htm` file, I think I understand what's going on:

```
Creating temporary file "c:\foo\build\RSP00001273601360.rsp" with contents
[
/GL /I &quot;..\include&quot; /I &quot;&quot; /D &quot;WIN32&quot; /D &quot;MORE_STUFF&quot; …
&quot;..\src\foo.c&quot;
]
Creating command line "cl.exe @"c:\foo\build\RSP00001273601360.rsp" /nologo /errorReport:prompt"
```

It seems that `/I` is followed by an empty argument, which somehow disappears (eaten up by a quirk of Windows command line parsing? Or of Visual C++?), so `/D` becomes the argument of `/I` and `WIN32` becomes an operand (which the compiler interprets as a source file name). (Feel free to comment if you think my interpretation is incorrect.)

I do need the project to work both when `EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR` is defined and when it isn't, because it is used for both automated and manual builds in slightly different circumstances.

How can I have an additional include directory specified by an environment variable, and not break the build when this environment variable is not defined?

Comment: That `EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR` must be having some critical files I guess, without which the build should not happen? I mean without stdio.h if you use printf in main() it should not let it build. Your understanding about `/I` is correct. It includes extra include directories to search in, including or apart, from the default directories.

Comment: @askmish I realize the stripped-down example I presented doesn't make much sense as is. There should be more directories after `EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR`: files in `EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR` can override other files found in subsequent directories.

Comment: @FinalContest Don't be silly. That question asks how to do some of the investigating legwork that I describe in my question. It has nothing to do with what I ask here, which is how to keep working both when `EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR` is defined and when it isn't defined.

Comment: That thread is exactly about this issue. If you miss something there, raise a bounty and/or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Silly workaround:

```
AdditionalIncludeDirectories="&quot;..\include&quot;;&quot;$(EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIR)\.&quot;"
```

So when the variable is present, the correct directory is searched; when the variable is absent, `\.` (i.e. the root directory of the current drive) is searched. Hopefully developers won't store parasitic `.h` files in the root directory.